# Blocking IO Thread in Quarkus Websocket

Tags: java, hibernate, websocket, quarkus, blocking

I have a websocket that receives data and I want to do some database operations with this data. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/my_socket")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MySocket {

  @Inject
  Event<MySocketMessage> messageEvent;

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(String message) {
    messageEvent.fire(new MySocketMessage(message));
  }
}
```

```
public class MySocketMessage {

  private final String message;

  public MySocketMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyDatabaseHandler {

  @Inject
  EntityManager entityManager;

  public void handleMessage(@Observes MySocketMessage message) {
    // Do some blocking database operations
    Object entity = new Object(message.getMessage());
    entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
}
```

Executing this code in the unit test causes no problems. But when I run the application I get this  exception:

```
2021-07-27 15:35:14,667 ERROR [ch.scs.mbv.veg.web.ScannerSocket] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-7) The my socket encountered the following error: : java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread.
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.checkBlocking(TransactionScopedSession.java:110)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.persist(TransactionScopedSession.java:134)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.ForwardingSession.persist(ForwardingSession.java:53)
        at
...
```

I understand that I am not supposed to execute blocking operations on an IO thread but I do not care about performance of the program because it will only have a single user. That is also the reason why I did not (and don't want to) make it reactive. A quick search showed that a very similar question has already been answered here: [blocking EntityManager operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778512/blocking-entitymanager-operations)
So I tried to put the @Blocking annotation in multiple places in my code but that did not have any effect at all, the exception keeps popping up. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found out that it is an bug of Quarkus version 1.13.3 that causes this error. I did not find a way to solve the problem using this version. However, switching to version 2.1.2 solved the problem!

In addition to switching to the newer version, I also had to add the following two lines in the file `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.websocket.dispatch-to-worker=true
quarkus.quartz.start-mode=forced
```

The second line is only necessary if Quartz is used somewhere in the project.